# Refactor if statemets

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

So atm im importing an excel doc into my project. I'm then using if statements to display the appropriate error message if any columns in the spreadsheet are empty.  My code is working but it just doesn't look tidy. Is there anyway to refactor all the if statements into a loop to display the error message, possibly another method which checks all?? checkIfColumnIsEmpty is a bool method which returns true if the column is empty

```
//if either column 0 and 1 are empty && column 2,3,4 and 5 are not
    if (!checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[0]) || !checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[1])
        && checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[2]) && checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[3])
         && checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[4]) && checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[5]))
    {
        if (checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[0]) && !checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[1]))
        {
            throw new ImportBOQException("Error importing document: First column is empty");
        }
        else if (!checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[0]) && checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[1]))
        {
            throw new ImportBOQException("Error importing document: Second column is empty");
        }

        else if (!checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[0]) && !checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[1]))
        {
            //all columns are valid so...
            Column0inSpreadsheet = r.ItemArray[0] as string;
            Column1inSpreadsheet = r.ItemArray[1] as string;

          //Other code which performs other operations, once the level as reached this far
        }
    }                                

    //if column 0 and 1 are NOT empty && Either column 2,3,4 or 5 is empty
    else if (checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[0]) && checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[1])
          || !checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[2]) || !checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[3])
           || !checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[4]) || !checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[5]))
    {
        if (checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[2]))
        {
            throw new ImportBOQException("Error importing document: Third column is empty");
        }
        else if (checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[3]))
        {
            throw new ImportBOQException("Error importing document: Fourth column is empty");
        }
        else if (checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[4]))
        {
            throw new ImportBOQException("Error importing document: Fifth column is empty");
        }
        else if (checkIfColumnisEmpty(r.ItemArray[5]))
        {
            throw new ImportBOQException("Error importing document: Sixth column is empty");
        }
        else
        //all columns are valid so...
        {   Column2inSpreadsheet = (r.ItemArray[2]) as string;
            Column3inSpreadsheet = (r.ItemArray[3]) as string;
            Column4inSpreadsheet = (r.ItemArray[4]) as string;
            Column5inSpreadsheet = (r.ItemArray[5]) as string;

            //Other code which performs other operations, once the level as reached this far
        }
    }
    else
    //other errors ot related to empty colums
    {
        throw new Exception("Error Uploading");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok, posted it there thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to check whether one of the columns is "empty" and get it's index, you can use this:

```
var firstEmptyColumn = r.ItemArray
    .Select((f, i) => new { Field=f, Index=i })
    .FirstOrDefault(x => r.IsNull(x.Index) || x.Field.ToString().Trim().Length == 0);
if (firstEmptyColumn != null)
{
    string errorMsg = string.Format("Error importing document: {0} column is empty",
        firstEmptyColumn.Index);
    throw new ImportBOQException(errorMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, convert r to class with named properties instead of using indexers for array and initialize collection from your source.
Second, create helper method with signature
bool VerifyColumn(string value, string propertyName). This is a base refactoring, maybe you will be able to change your logic from "Holy s***" to "that's a mess but we can change it!"

Comment: ok thanks for that, the ItemArray are columns being imported from the spread sheet e.g r.ItemArray[0] is the first column